# GridSeachCV with multiple scoring functions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Depending on the scoring function you pass to GridSearchCV  the results for grid.best_estomator_ might differ. I am wondering whether it is possible to run a single GridSearch in sklearn and in the output get several scores(or true values for the scoring function)?
Something like:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(model,param_grid,scoring=['mean_square_error','r2_score'])
```

And as output get:

```
clf.grids_cores_:
[MSE mean: -0.00000, R2 mean: -0.01975,: {'max_depth': 2, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'min_child_weight': 4, 'n_estimators': 25} 
MSE mean: -0.00001, R2 mean: -0.01975,: {'max_depth': 3, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'min_child_weight': 4, 'n_estimators': 25}, 
MSE mean: -0.00002, R2 mean: -0.01975,: {'max_depth': 4, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'min_child_weight': 4, 'n_estimators': 25}, etc)
```

The idea is to get a score for every valuation metric at every combination of model hyperparameters. Assume that I have 10 different scoring functions for GridSearchCV.  It will be extremely time consuming to run GridSearchCV 10 times to see which model parameters are best for every scoring function. The idea is to run it only once and get a number(score) for every scoring function within grid_scores_

It seems that it was almost implemented to sklearn in 2015, unfortunately the project was never finished: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2759
I'm looking for a way of doing this on my own.

Comment: The first question which comes to mind: how should sklearn evaluate your scorings (for ordering the scores)? Mean? Geometric mean? There are a lot of decisions.

Comment: Just a mean between different cross-folds

Comment: I think what @sascha means is how is sklearn supposed to know which evaluation method it should prioritize when searching for best mix of hyper-parameter settings? In your example, you pass two evaluation metrics but no indication of which is more important or how to weigh them. The desired output does show an ordering, and apparently the model was tuned to optimize for one of these, but which one? And why that one? These are decisions you will need to sort out before any implementation.